# Import custom libraries in Java

Tags: java, import

I need to import a Java class in my project. The class I need to import is in a JAR file with
absolute path `~/Documents/mylib/stdlib.jar`

Now in my source file (Test.java) I am using

`import stdlib.*;`

and I am compiling with
`javac -classpath ~/Documents/mylib/stdlib.jar Test.java`

And it is showing the error that stdlib does not exist.

Is my import statement correct or is there anything wrong with classpath?
Shouldn't this import statement import all the classes present in the JAR file?

I am not using any IDE and my OS is Linux.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/945962/java-problem-running-a-jar-file-in-command-line

Comment: Does not appear to be a duplicate of that question.

Comment: Could you provide compiler error?

Comment: Test.java:1: package stdlib does not exist
import stdlib.*;
^
1 error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The import statement imports classes from the jar file, not the jar file itself.

An import statement of the form:

```
  import stdlib.*;
```

will import all the classes in the *package* stdlib.

Oracle provides [this tutorial on import](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html).

**EDIT:** It looks like you're using the stdlib.jar for [An introduction to programming in Java](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/). The classes in this jar file have no packages. You don't need to import classes in the default package, since your class is also in the default package.

Comment: I need to import a class from the jar file.What should I do?

Comment: Say you want to import a class Foo that's in package com.bar -- in any jar file on the classpath. Then you could use either import com.bar.* OR import com.bar.Foo. The first imports all the public classes in the package; the latter, just one. If you're using an IDE, it may support adding the import for you.

Comment: Are you certain that the package stdlib exists inside the jar file? Can you provide a link to either the API docs or the library itself?

Comment: If there are no packages, then to import a class Foo just use "import Foo".

Comment: Well I tried just "import StdOut" (StdOut is the class I need to import which is in stdlib.jar which I set in classpath) but then also it is showing error

Comment: What do you see when you enter "javac -version"?

Comment: I tried import StdOut and it says : Test.java:1: '.' expected
import StdOut;
             ^
Test.java:1: ';' expected
import StdOut;
              ^
2 errors

Comment: Did you include a semicolon at the end: "import StdOut;" ? If you did, then can you show us your source code?

Comment: import StdOut;
public class Test{

   public static void main(String args[]){

   StdOut.println("Helloz");
  }
}

Comment: Okay, just take out the import. That should fix the problem. You don't need to import classes from the default package -- since your class is itself in the default package. It's unusual for classes not to be in a package, so this is less familiar for most of us.

Comment: @AndyThomas-Cramer In fact you *cannot* import classes from the default package.

Comment: Even after removing import I am getting error :   Test.java:6: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable StdOut
location: class Test
  StdOut.println("Helloz");
  ^
1 error

Comment: Is your class in a named package? If so, one fix is to move your class to the default package. Java no longer supports importing classes from the default package, since 1.4 or so.

Comment: By default package you mean current directory??

Comment: Above your source code for "class Test", do you have a "package" statement?

Comment: I compiled and ran your source code (minus the import) without error, using the library I guessed above. It worked. I think you're going to have to double-check everything in your environment.

Comment: I am able to compile the code without any error after removing the import.BUt on running the code it says a Class Not found exception for StdOut.I copied the StdOut.java in my current directory and I am getting the result but I want to dont want to copy the files everytime.So is my classpath settings correct : javac -classpath <path of stdlib.jar> Test.java

Answer (score 0):

It will import all classes immediately under the "stdlib" package, but nothing in sub-packages. You need to import the package(s) and classes; we can see inside the jar to know if your package name assumption is correct.

The class path itself is fine.

---

**Updated with information from comments.**

You say that you're trying to import a class in the default package. It is a syntax error to import a type from the default package. See the [JLS Section 7.5](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/packages.html#7.5) for details.

> It is a compile time error to import a type from the unnamed package.

If you must access this class you'll need to use reflection.

It would be much easier to put it in a named package, though.

Comment: The file I need to import is in the stdlib.jar file , no sub-packages

Comment: @user966518 You don't import a file, you import a package's classes, or a specific classes. What are the fully-qualified names of the classes in the jar?

Comment: StdOut.java
is the class I want to import

Comment: @user966518 I understand it's in the jar. What's the fully-qualified name (including the package) of the class? If it's in the default package, just import the class itself.

Comment: Well I dont know what "fully qualified name" means (I am noob).Its just that on extracting the jar file I get the class I need to import.The name of the jar is "stdlib.jar" and the file I need to import is "StdOut.java".So I need to know what import statement should I use "import stdlib.*;" or just "import StdOut".Also IS my classpath correct?

Comment: The classpath is fine. *We cannot see inside your jar.* We do not know what packages it contains. Do a `jar tf stdlib.jar` to see what the packages/classes are. We *know* you need to know the `import` statement to use, and we're trying to help with the limited information you're providing.

Comment: Better yet, do jar tf ~/Documents/mylib/stdlib.jar

Comment: this gives output: StdOut.java StdOut.class and other .java files.There are no other packages just plain .java in the jar.

Comment: I tried that it is still showing error :  Test.java:1: '.' expected
import StdOut;
             ^
Test.java:1: ';' expected
import StdOut;
              ^
2 errors

Comment: import StdOut; public class Test{ public static void main(String args[]){ StdOut.println("Helloz"); } }

Comment: Its saying that instead of semicolon after StdOut I should have a "."

Comment: @user966518 If your class is also in the default package, then you don't need to import the class at all.

Comment: But if I remove the import statement its not recognising StdOut in StdOut.println() statement. ERROR : Test.java:6: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable StdOut
location: class Test
  StdOut.println("Helloz");
  ^
1 error

Comment: Is your class in a named package?

Comment: Well I dont understand the concept of package very well.The class is in the "top-level" of the jar file so I guess it isnt in any package as such.

Comment: @user966518 He's asking about the class you're using StdOut in.

Comment: Right - in your own source code for class Test, do you see a "package" statement near the top?

Comment: Well,as I said I dont understand the concept of package very well so I dont know what it means.Its just a file Test.java in a directory.The source code of which I had written above.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$HOME` instead of `~`.

$HOME is expanded, ~ is not.

Comment: Shouldn't matter under most shells.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether `StdOut.java` has a declaration `package stdout;`.

Or is it just situated on the top-level folder in `stdout.jar`?

Comment: On extracting stdlib.jar (the jar file I set in classpath) I get StdOut.java (the class I need to import)