# Create runnable jar from command line

Tags: java

In folder `~/code/` I have
`bin/ src/ lib/`
    A manifest.txt is created in ~/ with the content:

```
Main-class: test.MyMainClass
Class-Path: lib/*.jar
```

Then in ~ I used command

`jar cfm d.jar manifest.txt code/`

then I run

`java -jar d.jar`

it says

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: test/MyMainClass
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test.MyMainClass`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: problem running a jar file in command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/945962/java-problem-running-a-jar-file-in-command-line)

Answer (score 3):

Why do you pack bin, src, and lib? You need to pack the compiled classes.

I.e. first, compile your project. You'll get some classes dir. Go to that dir and pack those files with `jar`.

Then you need to have `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` with the `Main-class: ...`

Check this nice article - last chapter.
http://www.skylit.com/javamethods/faqs/createjar.html

---

If this is the first time you play with Java, it's good to learn the basics - how the files in .jar are organized etc.

But later, to be efficient when building, I'd suggest you to use Maven.
http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html

Comment: up vote only because of the suggestion to learn a powerful tool like Maven instead of doing this tedious busy work for no reason.

Comment: Your answer is right but I think it might confuse the OP. He doesn't need to "compile the project" to "get some classes dir" if he already has the `bin/` directory - the compiled classes are in `bin/`.

Comment: @Edward how do you know that?