# java set classpath from php

Tags: java, php, classpath

I have this folder structure

```
C:\a\b.java
C:\a\b.class
C:\a\c.java
C:\a\c.class
C:\a\ftp.jar
```

From PHP, I used `exec("java b");` This executed `b.class` file. That is fine.
Now I should execute `c.class` file from PHP. In c.java, I have created an object for the class which is in ftp.jar. So I should set classpath for this. But I couldnt set classpath from PHP

But when I do it from cmd, all working fine. Please tell me how to set classpath from PHP?

Comment: That's a Nice one. Review http://stackoverflow.com/questions/945962/java-problem-running-a-jar-file-in-command-line

Comment: actually i don't Know anything in `PhP` , but as a `java` , what happen if you add this `jar` file to `java` classpath??

Answer (score 0):

This might work (provide explicit `cp` argument, I haven't tried though):

```
exec("java -cp  C:\a\d.jar c"); //if d.jar contains c.class
```

or

```
exec("java -cp  C:\a c"); //if d.jar doesn't contain c.class
```