# I can't figure out how to call Java oscar3 class method stringToString from the command line

Tags: java, jar, classpath, class-method

I'm trying to call a Java class method from the command line but the for the life of me can't figure out the syntax. The method is stringToString found in this class http://apidoc.ch.cam.ac.uk/oscar3/apidocs/uk/ac/cam/ch/wwmm/oscar3/Oscar3.html

What I have tried:

```
java -Xmx512m -classpath .:oscar3-a5:lib/oscar3-a5.jar uk.ac.cam.ch.wwmm.oscar3.Oscar3 stringToString "test"

java -Xmx512m -classpath .:oscar3-a5:lib/oscar3-a5.jar uk.ac.cam.ch.wwmm.oscar3 Oscar3(stringToString "test)

java -classpath .:oscar3-a5.jar:lib/uk.ac.cam.ch.wwmm.oscar3.Oscar3 stringToString "test"
```

It complains like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: uk/ac/cam/ch/wwmm/oscar3/Oscar3
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: uk.ac.cam.ch.wwmm.oscar3.Oscar3
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

I have also looked at this ([Java: how to import a jar file from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/945962/java-problem-running-a-jar-file-in-command-line)) for a solution but clearly I'm too retarded to see the obvious. If anyone knows the correct syntax for this any help would be great.

Comment: Are you running the command on Windows or a *nix platform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very close! I think you want the following:

`java -Xmx512m -cp oscar3-a5/oscar3-a5.jar uk.ac.cam.ch.wwmm.oscar3.Oscar3 stringToString test`

Alternatively if your current working directory (`pwd`) is the same directory that `oscar3-a5.jar` resides in, then:

`java -Xmx512m -cp ./oscar3-a5.jar uk.ac.cam.ch.wwmm.oscar3.Oscar3 stringToString test`

(I've assumed you're running on *nix - if you're running on Windows replace the `/` with `\`)

Comment: This was a huge help. It didn't run as written but I added oscar3-a5.jar to `/Library/Java/Extensions`. Once it was added to that directory I could call the public class method. It is too bad it didn't output the return value to the screen. I think I might have to fork it.