# Shell Command to run a main class from jar

Tags: java, shell

I am running a shell command to run a main class from a jar. I am using the following command-

```
java -cp ./knowledge-generator.jar com.abc.rdf.file.FileGenerator    --inputFiles `pwd`/abc.ttl --outputFolder `pwd`
```

But everythime I am getting the error-

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.abc.rdf.file.FileGenerator
```

I checked the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/945962/java-problem-running-a-jar-file-in-command-line) but that did not help me. What is going wrong here.

Comment: Did you package a runnable jar, i.e. did you put a manifest into the jar? The replace `-cp` with `-jar` and remove the explicit main class. Otherwise, this is too little information.

Comment: Check that your knowledge-generator.jar contains the mentioned class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following command to `run` jar -

```
java -jar ./knowledge-generator.jar
```

Comment: so I dont need to give the main class name?

Comment: If the jar has a manifest, it should specify the `Main-Class`, which is the entry point.

Answer (score 0):

Add the full path of the jar that you're adding to your classpath. For example:

```
java -cp C:/myprog/knowledge-generator.jar com.abc.credit.data.knowledgegenerator.KnowledgeGenerator --inputFiles `pwd`/CIA_CP_LDM.ttl --outputFolder `pwd`
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting means that the class you are specifiying is not found on the classpath.

This could be eiether because you have mispelled the class name or the class itself or the jar file containing it is not on the classpath.

Since you are usging `./knowledge-generator.jar` this means that the jar file is located on the same directory from where you are executing the command (current wurking directory). make sure the jar file is there (execute the command ls) and that the jar file contains the class you are trying to use as entry point to your java application