# Running an eclipse created jar file

Tags: eclipse, jar, executable-jar

I have created a jar file in eclipse and now I want to execute the jar file in command prompt.

How can I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: problem running a jar file in command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/945962/java-problem-running-a-jar-file-in-command-line)

Answer (score 0):

Run this command from command prompt:

```
java -jar <JarName>.jar
```

Note: you will need to jar a file called META-INF/MANIFEST.MF in order to run the jar after compilation.

**If you are creating the jar using Eclipse do this:**

- Go to file > Export > Java > Jar file (hit next)
- Select your project and all the files you would like to jar
- Type below the destination of the jar (e.g. c:\MyJar.jar) (hit next x2)
- On the bottom Main class either hit browse and choose the class which contains main or type: package_name.class_name (wihch contains the main entry point)
- Hit Finish
- Go to the jar location in command prompt and run as i mentioned above

Comment: Please post the error you are receiving when trying to run the command above. also see if you can run java -version from the location you are trying to run the jar and post what’s happening.

Answer (score 0):

When your creating jar file using eclipse
While reaching JAR manifest specification
**enter main class**

[image]