# ms access database and jar file

Tags: java, database, ms-access, jdbc, ucanaccess

guyz i have been working on a small project and its basically a admission system in java i have used ms access as my database in which a student record is inserted, searched and deleted.

i have used UCanAccess as my driver for jdbc:odbc and is working absolutely fine on my local machine but when i copy paste the jar file and database in other machine it gives me a null pointer exception

while the snapshot of jar files which i used in project is also attached with this problem

i created the Database folder with same name in other computer i.e E://Database/StudentDatabase.accdb

and pasted the database there i also gave him the path from the odbc driver in control panel system DSN

note:

1. other machine has also jdk installed
2. on my local machine in which i developed the software has office 2007 pro and windows is 64-bit
3. while the machine or computer in which i want my jar file and database to work is also 64-bit and office 2013 pro can office different versions make problems

thankful for your reply and comment

[image]

Comment: Can you provide full traceback of exception? Also, how are you running the java program? If from command line you need to include [.jar files in classpath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/945962/java-how-to-import-a-jar-file-from-command-line?rq=1).

Comment: not i m not running from command prompt because jdk is installed i am running by just double clicking on jar file like an exe file in c++ is runned more over the error it gaves me is NULL POINTER EXCEPTION

Comment: @Parfait are u there ?

Comment: How did you develop the .jar file? Is there no .java code you compiled to a .class object? Can you post full code to see import lines and even try/catch handling. And again, please post full error. If only that one line outputs, then your catch may not print out full message?

Comment: thankx bro i have solved it out

Comment: Please answer your own question to help a future reader of your post!