# Running a class that relies on Jar file in terminal

Tags: java

For my intro computer science class they recommend using eclipse as an IDE. I have used vim in the past and would prefer using it. There are two `.jar` files that the programs we create rely off of, because it is an intro class and we are not using java's `main` class functionality.

Right now we download the two `.jar` files and then use the Eclipse IDE `build path` function to link the `.jar` files with our code. Then when we run on Eclipse IDE it works perfectly fine.

How would I do this in ubuntu terminal? Thank you!

TLDR;
Intro comp sci class wants us to use eclipse, I want to use vim. How do you `build path` for a jar file to work with my `class` code in the ubuntu terminal.

Looked at this link and did not work
[Java: how to import a jar file from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/945962/java-how-to-import-a-jar-file-from-command-line)

Update of image[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: how to import a jar file from command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/945962/java-how-to-import-a-jar-file-from-command-line)

Comment: Looked at that, didn't work

Comment: I know you love vim, but until you get it over that, and start using an IDE you will not be a productive java developer, or at least not nearly as productive as you could be.

Comment: @MeBigFatGuy Thank you for that! I will start testing out the IDE once I get vim working

Comment: @CtrlAltDelete : the path of your class must match its package : `com/mypackage/lab1.class`. Also add `.` to the classpath, it is the current directory .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You specify the jar files with a CLASSPATH, either using a CLASSPATH environment variable

```
export CLASSPATH="a.jar:b.jar"
java com.mypackage.MyClass
```

or on the command line with `-cp` like

```
java -cp a.jar:b.jar com.mypackage.MyClass
```

Comment: Are you sure the package you are mentioning in the command line is the correct one?

Comment: Yes, there are two .jar files one is for testing one is for images. We are not creating any images this lab so I only need the one .jar file

Comment: remove the colon sign after the jar. Its the separator when multiple ones are to be added

Comment: Still says: `Could not find or load main class com.mypackage.lab1`

Comment: and what i meant with my previous comment was that are you sure `com.mypackage.lab1` is the correct package for your class

Comment: Where it says  ".mypackage" am I supposed to enter the name of a package? If so that is the problem, I never created a package. Is that is what is wrong?

Comment: Yes when people write mypackage/myclass they mean **your** package or class.

Answer (score 0):

Include your jar dependencies while executing from command line.

```
java -cp tester.jar lab1
```

Comment: This doesn't work `Error: Could not find or load main class lab1`

Comment: Do I need to make a package before doing this

Comment: Are you sure your lab1 class includes the main method in it? And no you dont compulsorily need a package. but to start off you are better without it.
Please consider using an IDE like Eclipse to resolve the basic mistakes easily.

Comment: The lab1 class does not have a main method in it, I mentioned that above. I will use an IDE but I want to figure out how it works before I use it. I like knowing how things work before I use them

Comment: Then please take a look at the numerous Java tutorials about how Java programs work before you start writing code! https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_quick_guide.htm is one of the thousands available.
The `main` method is the entry point of the Java class which the JVM seeks and starts executing. Without it, it cant get in and start execution, hence the runtime error